# Creating a dynamic table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to create a dynamic table using JavaScript. I need the table to take the form of a scheduler (hour blocks for 24 hours) It has to span a full 24 columns for the hours with a header for each block. 12am, 1am...11pm, etc. However, I'm currently restricted to the first col for the headers. My knowledge of JavaScript is at a beginner level. This is a basic representation of what I need and what is broken. What would be the best way to fix this code or implement something better?

```
function populateTable(table, time, rows, cells, content) {
            if (!table) table = document.createElement('table');
                var head = document.createElement('thead');
                var title = document.createElement('th');

                head.appendChild(title);
                    for (var x = 1; x <= time; x++){
                    table.appendChild(head);
                    title.appendChild(document.createTextNode(x));
                    }
                var body = document.createElement('tbody');
                    for (var i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
                        var row = document.createElement('tr');
                            for (var j = 0; j < cells; ++j) {
                            row.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
                            row.cells[j].appendChild(document.createTextNode(content + (j + 1)));
                            }
                        table.appendChild(row);
                    }
                return table;
                }
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    document.getElementById('scheduleTable')
                    .appendChild(populateTable(null,12,12, 12, "content"));
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to change the top part to:

```
var head = document.createElement('thead');
table.appendChild(head);

for (var x = 1; x <= time; x++) {
    var title = document.createElement('th');
    title.appendChild(document.createTextNode(x));
    head.appendChild(title);
}
```

If you want the title cells to be spread out correctly.